# SVG rotation in IE (all) fails

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, animation, svg

I have an SVG animation that requires a spinning element. SMIL and css based animations are out of the question as IE does not support them and the beginElement() property is also not supported in IE or Firefox. IE sizing is not the problem as CSS fixes that very well.

The problem is that it is not a standard shape (rect, circle or so on) so the svg animate attributes fail in spectacular fashion as there is not a central point by default - getBBox() is the preferred method.

I have a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wpr8Rpcdp2MVerjAhffq?p=preview) with an example of the svg within html. The script is necessarily within the svg for ease of portability and I have got it to work in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but IE fails to rotate the element although no errors are shown. the JS is below:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function init(evt) {
  addRotateTransform('spinner', 1.5, 1);
}

function addRotateTransform(target_id, dur, dir) {
  var my_element = document.getElementById(target_id);
  var a = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "animateTransform");

  var bb = my_element.getBBox();
  var cx = bb.x + bb.width/2;
  var cy = bb.y + bb.height/2;

  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeName", "transform");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeType", "XML");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "type", "rotate");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "dur", dur + "s");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "repeatCount", "indefinite");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "from", "0 "+cx+" "+cy);
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "to", 360*dir+" "+cx+" "+cy);

  my_element.appendChild(a);
  try {
    a.beginElement(); // this works in Chrome
  }
  catch(err) {
    window.setTimeout(init, 0); // this works in FF
  }
}
```

Comment: IE does not support SMIL. You could try fakeSmile (https://leunen.me/fakesmile/)

Comment: Thanks Robert, using another library won't help here as it needs to be an encapsulated thingemebob and fakeSmile doesn't (yet) appear to support rotation.

Comment: The you'll need to use pure javascript and manipulate the DOM.

Comment: That's why I am posing the above problem. I have been unable to find a suitable solution - or at least don't know the right question, so the plunk was my favoured approach as it puts it in context when viewed in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version using javascript.  It just useres a `timeout()` to update a transform on the path.

```html
    <h1>SVG spinner</h1>
    <p>The javascript should be placed within the svg to maintain portability throughout different projects as we don't want to load all of the libraries required for a simple loading screen.</p>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 251.3 136" enable-background="new 0 0 251.3 136" xml:space="preserve" onload="init(evt)">
<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[

  var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

  function init(evt) {
    addRotateTransform('spinner', 0);
  }


  function addRotateTransform(target_id, angle) {
    var my_element = document.getElementById(target_id);
    var bb = my_element.getBBox();
    var cx = bb.x + bb.width/2;
    var cy = bb.y + bb.height/2;

    my_element.setAttribute("transform", "rotate("+angle+","+cx+","+cy+")");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      addRotateTransform('spinner', angle+2);
    }, 16);
  }

]]></script>
<!-- The rest of the svg has been removed from here -->
<g>
  <path id="spinner" opacity="0.6" fill="#ed1b1e" d="M228.4,82.8c7.5,1.3,15.1-2.5,18.5-9.3c3.7-7.4,1.2-16.8-5.8-21.2c-0.9-0.6-1.8-1-2.8-1.4
    c-0.2-0.1-1-0.2-1.1-0.4c-0.1-0.1,0-1.1,0-1.3c-0.2-1.6-1.2-2.9-2.6-3.6c-1.3-0.7-2.6-0.5-4-0.4c-1.9,0.2-3.7,0.7-5.4,1.4
    c-7.4,3.1-11.9,10.3-11.9,18.2C213.1,73.7,220,81.4,228.4,82.8z m-7.9,-15.6c-0.4-2,0.3-4.5,1.2-6.3c1.1-2.2,2.9-4,5.2-5.1
    c1.9-0.9,3.7-0.9,5.7-1c2.2-0.1,4-1.6,4.5-3.7c5.8,2.3,9.7,8.3,9.2,14.6c-0.3,3.6-2,7-4.7,9.3c-2.8,2.4-5.9,3.2-9.5,3.2
    c0.3,0-0.2,0-0.3-0.1c-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.1-1.8-0.3c-1.8-0.4-3.5-1.3-4.9-2.4C222.4,73.4,220.9,70.5,220.5,67.2
    C220.4,66.8,220.5,67.4,220.5,67.2z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's awesome!! Thank a lot. I'll update the plunk to show the working version.